# how can i set all variables from my NSMutableArray to zero?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to set integer variables that I have put in an `NSMutableArray` to zero, here is my code so far but it doesn't work:

```
[self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount1]];
[self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount2]];
[self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount3]];
[self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount4]];
[self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount5]];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.pressCountArray count]; i++){

    [[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]  == 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing integer value with `0` and not assigning.

Just this code can accomplish your task

```
self.pressCountArray[i] = @0;
```

Comment: `[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] == @0` compares object pointers and does not assign a new value.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah thanks, forgot to remove extra `=`, copy-paste mistake. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] == 0
```

*compares* the current value with zero. To set a new value, use just

```
self.pressCountArray[i] = @0;
```

`@0` is a "NSNumber literal" and equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`,
see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html.

You can also simplify your existing code with "boxed expressions":

```
[self.pressCountArray addObject:@(self.presscount1)];
// ...
```